# How to open a new activity when an item of a fragment with RecyclerView is clicked while passing the data of the clicked custom list item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener

I have made a custom Place object and Place Adapter. I have used Parcelable but nothing happens when I click any item of the Fragments

Tried using Parcelable but no response on clicking any item.

**Place Object**

```
public class Place implements Parcelable {


/** String resource ID for the name of the place */
private int mPlaceID;

private int mImageResourceId;

private int mNearestStation;

private int mSiteInfo;

public Place(int placeID, int imageResourceId, int NearestStation, int 
SiteInfo) {
    mPlaceID = placeID;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    mNearestStation = NearestStation;
    mSiteInfo = SiteInfo;
}

protected Place(Parcel in) {
    mImageResourceId = in.readInt();
    mPlaceID = in.readInt ();
    mNearestStation = in.readInt ();
    mSiteInfo = in.readInt ();

}

public static final Creator<Place> CREATOR = new Creator<Place>() {
    @Override
    public Place createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Place (in);
    }

    @Override
    public Place[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Place[size];
    }
};

/**
 * Get the string resource ID for the name of the place.
 */
public int getPlaceName() {
    return mPlaceID;
}

/**
 * Return the image resource ID of the place.
 */
public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

public int getNearestStation() {
    return mNearestStation;
}

public int getSiteInfo() {
    return mSiteInfo;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(mImageResourceId);
    parcel.writeInt(mPlaceID);
    parcel.writeInt ( mNearestStation );
    parcel.writeInt ( mSiteInfo );
}

}
```

**Place Adapter**

```
public class PlaceAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
List<Place> mData;

public static class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mImageView;

    public PlaceViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ImageViewText );
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ImageView );

    }
}

public PlaceAdapter(Context mContext, List<Place> mData){

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from ( mContext ).inflate ( 
R.layout.list_item, parent, false );
    PlaceViewHolder pvh = new PlaceViewHolder ( v );
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaceViewHolder holder, int 
position) {


    holder.mTextView.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getPlaceName () );
    holder.mImageView.setImageResource ( mData.get ( position 
).getImageResourceId () );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size ();
}

public interface OnPlaceListener{

    void onPlaceClick(int position);
}

}
```

**This is one of the fragments where I click the item**

```
public class MonumentsFragment extends Fragment implements 
PlaceAdapter.OnPlaceListener {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public MonumentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.places_list, container, 
false);


    final List<Place> places = new ArrayList<> ();

    Place place1 = new Place(R.string.monument1, 
R.drawable.windsor_castle, R.string.monument1S, R.string.monument1I);
    places.add(place1);

    Place place2 = new Place(R.string.monument2, 
R.drawable.trafalgar_square,R.string.monument2S, R.string.monument2I);
    places.add(place2);

    Place place3 = new Place(R.string.monument3, 
R.drawable.buckingham_palace,R.string.monument3S, R.string.monument3I);
    places.add(place3);

    Place place4 = new Place(R.string.monument4, 
R.drawable.bank_of_england,R.string.monument4S, R.string.monument4I);
    places.add(place4);

    Place place5 = new Place(R.string.monument5, 
R.drawable.kensington_palace,R.string.monument5S, R.string.monument5I);
     places.add(place5);

    Place place6 = new Place(R.string.monument6, 
R.drawable.london_wall,R.string.monument6S, R.string.monument6I);
    places.add(place6);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById ( 
R.id.recycler_view );
    PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter ( getContext (), places 
);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( getActivity 
() ) );
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter ( placeAdapter );

    return rootView;



}

@Override
public void onPlaceClick(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MonumentsFragment.this.getActivity () 
,SelectedPlaceActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("Place Item", position);
    startActivity ( intent );
}


}
```

**This is the Activity I want to open on clicking**

```
public class SelectedPlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.selected_place);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent!=null) {
        Place currentPlace = intent.getParcelableExtra("Place Item");


        int imageRes = currentPlace.getImageResourceId ();

        int placeName = currentPlace.getPlaceName ();

        int nearestStation = currentPlace.getNearestStation ();

        int moreInfo = currentPlace.getSiteInfo ();

        ImageView placeImage = findViewById (R.id.selected_place_image );
        TextView namePlace = findViewById ( R.id.selected_place_name );
        TextView station = findViewById ( R.id.nearest_station );
        TextView information = findViewById ( R.id.more_info );


        placeImage.setImageResource(imageRes);
        namePlace.setText(placeName);
        station.setText(nearestStation);
        information.setText ( moreInfo );
    }

}
}
```

No response on clicking any of the items in the fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not assigned the listener to the `onClick` of the item and passed the listener to the constructor of the adapter. Please follow the below steps.

**Step 1**
Declare the listener in the `PlaceAdapter` class and assign the value to it by passing it through the constructor as given below.

```java
// declare the listener
OnPlaceListener mListener;

// pass the listener along with Context and the List
public PlaceAdapter(Context mContext, List<Place> mData, OnPlaceListener listener){

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    // assign the listener
    this.mListener = listener;

}
```

**Step 2**
You need to assign the listener to the onClick of the itemView inside your `onBindViewHolder` method

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaceViewHolder holder, int
        position) {
    // assign the listener here
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            mListener.onPlaceClick(position);
        }
    });
    holder.mTextView.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getPlaceName () );
    holder.mImageView.setImageResource ( mData.get ( position
    ).getImageResourceId () );

}
```

**Step 3**
In the fragment pass the listener to the adapter.

```java
PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(getContext(), places, this);
```

**Also**, I noted you're passing the positon to the intent. Instead, you need to pass the Place object related to that position

```java
@Override
public void onPlaceClick(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MonumentsFragment.this.getActivity ()
            ,SelectedPlaceActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("Place Item", places.get(position));
    startActivity ( intent );
}
```

**Note** you need to declare the List outisde `onCreateView` to access it from the `onPlaceClick` method.

```java
public class MonumentsFragment extends Fragment implements
        PlaceAdapter.OnPlaceListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    // Declare the list here
    private List<Place> places;

    public MonumentsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.places_list, container,
                false);
        // initialize the list 
        places = new ArrayList<>();

        Place place1 = new Place(R.string.monument1, 
                                 R.drawable.windsor_castle, R.string.monument1S, R.string.monument1I);
        places.add(place1);

        // rest of the code
```

Comment: I followed all the steps but in the last one it says unresolved 'places' when i try to write places.get(position). Also this is another error i am getting -java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tourguide/com.example.tourguide.ui.main.SelectedPlaceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.tourguide.ui.main.Place.getImageResourceId()' on a null object reference

Comment: @VihaanMisra make sure that you're invoking methods on existing items. So check if you provide the correct pointers and pass the right items into the method calls. And don't be afraid of making researches about all this, the network is full of already answered questions like this one.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot dude you are damn great!! How long have you been coding, I have just started and i really want to be able to solve other's problems like this. Do you have any tips for me to become a really great programmer because many times i just go blank and have no idea what to do. Thanks again man!!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to click on items in your `RecyclerView` you need to provide an `setOnClickListener` on the item. For example, you could do it inside `onCreateViewHolder` of your adapter.

```
public ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, viewGroup, false);
    final ExampleViewHolder holder = new ExampleViewHolder(view);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // actions that you need to perform
        }
    });

    return holder;
}
```

If you need to get item position you can use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` for it. If you need additional explanation, please provide more details about needed result.

If you're using inner interface for that, you could use `listener.onPlaceClick(holder.getAdapterPosition())` and override needed method to open new activity or put the code inside the adapter and use `mData.get()` to get your object for `intent`. You can get `context` from `v`.

--- Update ---

To be able to start activity from the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class you need to pass the context. There are two ways, you can get it from the `View` or assign the context in your constructor.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), *needed_activity_class*);
          // put all that you need in intent
          v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
      }
 });
```

Comment: I need to open the SelectedPlaceActivity when an item of MuseumsFragment is clicked and pass one image view id and three text view IDs that are associated with every item of custom array 'Place'

Comment: @VihaanMisra check the second answer, it already got details that you're looking for

Comment: Is there a method to do so without using an inner interface as it is confusing me so i would have no problem to remove it? I need to declare a new intent and then start the required activity. I'm a beginner so it would be very helpful for me if you could provide the code also. Thanks!

Comment: @VihaanMisra give me a moment to update the answer.